# How to run triggers of one object from another object in expression blend 4?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, expression-blend

We have a project where we have a set of buttons which we want to programm in expBlend4.

Here they are:
[example](http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/802/kt0z.jpg)

When we press first button and call trigger - OnMouseLeftButtonDown1 - we change button image background.

Then when we press another button with same trigger - this second button changed the same way as a first.

We want to run a blank trigger for button1 wich will change background image to default unpressed state.

For example - OnStylusMove.

But how we can't access to triggers of button1 from button2.

How we can do this?

Comment: What type of project? Silverlight, WPF, WP, etc? Do you only know how to use the Blend interface or is there any familiarity with the XAML directly?

Comment: WPF project. We use expBlend4 interface. And programm separate button sucseccfull. But we can't get to buttons storyboard from code of the class.

I think there might be a XAML problem... We don't know how to declare expBlend storyboard in XAML to use it from class.

Please give me some advice. Usefull links.

Comment: Well you don't absolutely NEED Blend, but it is very helpful quite often. As for manipulating between the two, well if I'm understanding correctly then you basically want the same behavior as a Radio button group where if one shows selected then the other does not, and vice versa right? If that's the case you could just literally use two (or more) Radio Buttons, assign a GroupName, and toggle their properties without all the fuss of assigning your own triggers. Then it's just a matter of styling them to look however you want.